# Почему мне выводит смайл в c++

Tags: c++

Я сделал задачу, но почему то мне выводит смайл , хотя по логике должен вывестись массив чар

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 void f(char c[1000] ){
    int g=strlen(c);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(c);i++){
        if(g>i){
            swap(c[g],c[i]);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
        g--;
    }
    cout<< c[1000];
}
int main(){
    char a[1000];
    gets(a);
    f(a);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И что, `gets` скомпилировался?... А вообще - он просто выводит первый за пределами массива символ. Ну вот случайно там лежал именно смайлик :) Массив у вас из 1000 элементов, в `cout << c[1000]` вы просите вывести 1001-й элемент.

Comment: Ну я попробовал через ```for``` выводить , но ничего не выводит .И да ```gets```каким то чудом скомпилировался , хотя я уже поменял на син. @Harry

Comment: @Harry Спасибо! Вы очень помогли)